# How to get more specific errors when validating XML against an XSD using java.xml.validator

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

After searching for the best approach to validating my XML against an XSD, I came across java.xml.validator.

I started off by using the example code from the API and adding my own ErrorHandler

```
// parse an XML document into a DOM tree
DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = parser.parse(new File("instance.xml"));

// create a SchemaFactory capable of understanding WXS schemas
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

// load a WXS schema, represented by a Schema instance
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File("mySchema.xsd"));
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

// create a Validator instance, which can be used to validate an instance document
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

// Add a custom ErrorHandler
validator.setErrorHandler(new XsdValidationErrorHandler());

// validate the DOM tree
try {
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // instance document is invalid!
}

...

private class XsdValidationErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        throw new SAXException(exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        throw new SAXException(exception.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        throw new SAXException(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This works fine, however, the message passed to my XsdValidationErrorHandler is doesn't give me any indication of exactly where in the document the offending XML is:

```
"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'X'. One of '{Y}' is expected."
```

Is there a way for me to override or plug-in another section of Validator, so that I can define my own error messages sent to the ErrorHandler without having to rewrite all of the code?

Should I be using a different library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try catching SaxParseException, it's a descendant of SaxException. If you get one of them it has methods getLineNumber(), getColumnNumber() etc.

Comment: You're correct, it does have a getLineNumber() method - I had missed this. The line number is something meaningful too - if I can't manage to get some slightly more specific information from the data itself then I can use this.

Answer (score 3):

Validate at the time you parse. This will make the location information available, and the ErrorHandler will report it.

Simply create the `Schema` before you create the `DocumentBuilderFactory`, and apply it like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setValidating(false);
dbf.setSchema(schema);
```

Note: the `setValidating()` method tells the DBF whether or not to use DTD validation. Setting the schema tells it to use schema validation.

Comment: This is a great answer, since `getLineNumber()` and `getColumnNumber` called on `SAXParseException` would return -1 given the scenario in the question. However, I would like the answer extended with information that the parser needs an error handler. Took me a while to figure out exactly how to get it right.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `exception.getLineNumber()` and `exception.getColumnNumber()` to get the coords of the error. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348285/how-to-get-errors-line-number-while-validating-a-xml-file-against-a-xml-schema) is a similar question.

Comment: is there any way to get the tag name which got error

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at [SAXParseException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXParseException.html)?  I assume you are looking for information like the [line number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXParseException.html#getLineNumber%28%29)?  As @parcifel mentioned, you should validate when you parse (more efficient and better error information).  you would do this by [specifying the schema on the DocumentBuilderFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setSchema%28javax.xml.validation.Schema%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class KitXsdErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        handleMessage("Warning", exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        handleMessage("Error", exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        handleMessage("Fatal", exception);
    }

    private String handleMessage(String level, SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        int lineNumber = exception.getLineNumber();
        int columnNumber = exception.getColumnNumber();
        String message = exception.getMessage();
        throw new SAXException("[" + level + "] Sətr nömrə: " + lineNumber + " Sütun nömrə: " + columnNumber + " message: " + message);
    }
}
```

This info are helpful too

[How to get internalization with validation messages of SAX XML Schema Validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565861/how-to-get-internalization-with-validation-messages-of-sax-xml-schema-validator)

http://vijiprakash.blogspot.com/2008/05/custom-error-message-in-xml-xsd.html